# REST equivalent for a isVerb kind of method (boolean response)

Tags: api, rest, boolean, restful-url

I am new to REST and have some trouble finding the proper RESTful url for an API.

I have an API that, given a word, returns a JSON with a boolean that indicates if the word is a verb or not. So in a not restful universe, this API would be a `isVerb` method. I am having trouble with finding a proper RESTful noun for the url of my API (as verbs are not allowed in REST).

I already have an API that given a string returns the verbs in that string (the actual `GET /verbs`) so the option myapi.com/verbs is not possible (and wouldn't be 100% right for my problem, as  I am not getting verbs, but getting a boolean).

Any hints? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there are two use-cases:

- 1) Extracting verbs from a string and
- 2) Test if a word is a verb.

Here is how I would decompose the problem:

A)  You have two inputs, a string and a word; but both can be abstracted out just as an array of words,

```
a strings = [‘word1’, ‘word2’, …]
```

B) To think of “/verbs/” as a space for all verbs

Then the problem becomes to just get a set of verbs out of the ‘virtual’ verbs space in ‘/verbs/’ by providing inputs (a string of words).

The API to access '/verbs/'could be in two forms:

A)  GET /verbs/?text=‘word’,…

Return: OK with the subset of text that are verb

Return: Not found

B)  GET /verbs/{word}/

Return: OK with the ‘word’ if it is a verb

Return: Not found

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `'/verbs'` path is very good in this scenario. But if it already has been taken consider something similar, for example: `'/verbsResource'`, `'/versSet'`, ...

This service will return (for `GET` request):

- status code `HTTP 200 OK` when given string is a verb;
- status code `HTTP 404 Not Found` when given string is NOT a verb.

So there are no boolean values.

Comment: Returning 404 wouldn't be confusing for the API consumer? It could give the impression that the user did something wrong in the API request.

Comment: According to 'RESTFull best practices' You should use `HTTP` status codes to inform API client what was operation result. Thus `404` should not by confusing for  consumner (http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html). You can also add some message to response with more accurate explanation.